# Finding a regex that allows only for a certain number range and nothing else

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin and on a field only want the user to have the opportunity to input only four numbers {1 or 2 or 3 or 4} respectively.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
 "onetofourOnly",
    function(value, element) {
        // need to update here
        return value.match(/(?:[0-4]){0,1}/);
    },
    "Please enter a number from 1 to 4."
);
```

Here I call the rule:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    numberField: {
        onetofourOnly : true
    },
  }
});
```

My logic is wrong though, so what would be the approriate regex for specifying those four numbers I want and *nothing else*?

Comment: You're apparently using the **jQuery Validate plugin**.  The jQuery Validation Engine is something else entirely.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this regex:

```
/^[1-4]$/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/uO4lL3/1).

```
>>> var re = /^[1-4]$/
>>> re.test("1")
... true
>>> re.test("0")
... false
```